# Save energy previewcam, android

Tags: android

I need some help.I take picture with an android device from my camera only in the preview mode.
Now I want to save some energy, I get an intent if I need a picture from the cam.
Actually the preview runs the hole time. I want stop the preview If I don't need them.

If I only stop the Preview with

```
camera.stopPreview();
```

saves this energy? And then I only start the

```
            camera.startPreview();
```

a short moment before I take a picture from the previewcallback.
Is this a efficient way?

Comment: You get an intent from whom?

Comment: To example from the alarmmanager.